# Is there a better way to edit context menus in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate?

Tags: context-menu, visual-studio-2012

I've installed a bunch of extensions in VS2012 and now there are way too many items in my context menu (i.e. right-click in code window). I know I can edit the menu in Tools -> Customize -> Commands, but frankly, this editor is not very user-friendly. There are a whole bunch of items that don't actually show up when I right-click in my editor, you can't move items to submenus, and when I want to manually add some command to a submenu I often can't find it.

Is there a better way to edit this menu (and others)? Maybe some extension or third-party software that I can't find for some reason? Even directly editing the XML seems user-friendlier if I knew where to find it...

Comment: No; There is no other way.

Comment: Oh my! What I would give to have something else apart from Microsoft's terrible context menu editor.

Comment: Microsoft hates us.